# My footer won't stay at the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 72px;
    margin: 0; 
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;

}


footer, .push {
    height: 60px; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
    max-width:100%;
}

/** Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait -http://ryanfait.com/ */

.cf:before
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
```

HTML

```
<div class="cf"></div>

<div class="push"></div>
</main>
<footer><div>
<ul>
<li>NAME</li>
<li>DESIGN</li>
<li>Portoflio </li>
</ul>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I do?

Comment: change `position:relative`  to `position:absolute` and add `bottom:0;` to footer in css

Comment: Please read and fully adapt the sample code where you found it and your problem will go away ... http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: @soffili - welcome to stack overflow, when you ask a question please try to make a fiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in CSS go:

```
footer {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 72px;
    margin: 0; 
    position: fixed; <---
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    bottom:0; <---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your entire contents before the footer in a wrapping element. The example you are reading is [propably this one.](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) Using a fixed element on the footer is something I would not suggest in this matter.